# Can anyone advise on variable syntax in RPM patch?

Tags: rpm-spec

I have the following patch referenced in my spec file.  It works with proxy hardcoded but I need to use a variable, which fails.  Can anyone please advise on the correct syntax?

```
diff --git .yarnrc.yml .yarnrc.yml
index 6cc7483..b560e95 100644
--- .yarnrc.yml
+++ .yarnrc.yml
@@ -1,4 +1,8 @@
 enableTelemetry: false
+enableStrictSsl: false
+networkConcurrency: 1
+httpProxy: %{http_proxy}
+httpsProxy: %{https_proxy}

 nodeLinker: pnp
```

UPDATE:

Comments don't seem to format well so throwing latest incarnation taking onboard reply from Aaron here, which also fails to build (in jenkins). Edited patch verified in jenkins console.

From spec file

```
%prep
%setup -n %{name}-%{version}
sed -i 's|httpProxy:.*|httpProxy: "'$http_proxy'"|g' %{PATCH0}
sed -i 's|httpsProxy:.*|httpsProxy: "'$https_proxy'"|g' %{PATCH0}
%patch0
```

Revised patch

```
diff --git .yarnrc.yml .yarnrc.yml
index 6cc7483..7c3f6df 100644
--- .yarnrc.yml
+++ .yarnrc.yml
@@ -1,4 +1,9 @@
enableTelemetry: false
+enableStrictSsl: false
+networkConcurrency: 1
+httpProxy: ******
+httpsProxy: ******

 nodeLinker: pnp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RPM isn't going to replace those lines in the diff file; you will need some script or something to do that for you before the build. Or you can put it in as part of your `%build` macro like `sed -i -e "s/_HTTP_PROXY_/%{http_proxy}/g" .yarnrc.yml` where the `yml` file you have in your source has a placeholder `_HTTP_PROXY_` ...

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I was afraid it was so; shame as it would be a useful feature.  Rather than split between patch and spec file, I'll try implement in spec file alone as follows.  Note that it (specifically proxy) must be near top of .yarnrc.yml file.


        sed -i '1i\httpProxy: "'$http_proxy'"\
        httpsProxy: "'$https_proxy'"\
        networkConcurrency: 1\
        enableStrictSsl: false' %{_builddir}/%{name}-%{version}/.yarnrc.yml

Comment: It is odd as the only method that successfully builds is when I include real proxy URL.  I should clarify that I am building in jenkins.  I verified the edited yarnrc.yml in jenkins so unsure why it fails.

Comment: I eventually decided to configure the options in specfile as follows, yarn config set 'parameter' 'value'.